# Entity not displaying properly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, windows-7, unicode, cross-browser, entity

I don't know this question is an valid one or not. I am using Firefox 15.0 on Windows 7 OS. And i have written an html code like this

```
<html>
<body>
 <p>&#8270;This my testing text1 </p>
 <p>*This my testing text2 </p>
 <p>*This my testing text3 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run this code on Firefox 15.0 and Windows 7, That **LOW ASTERISK(⁎)** is working fine. And i am running this same code on Firefox 17.0 and Windows Xp its not working. What is the problem.

In same Windows 7 os this entity is not displaying on Chrome,IE, its works only on Firefox.
But the same Firefox not working in Windows xp. Is there any font i have to install or what i have to do.
Can any one help me..

Comment: Are they using fonts that include that glyph?

Comment: Sorry @Alex K. , I can't get you. What you asking..?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534367/html-entities-and-charset-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this page using Chrome, and the character is displayed.

What font definition do you use? SO has

```
font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
```

and DejaVu Sans is also in the [list of fonts supporting this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/204e/fontsupport.htm).

Most likely, FF uses a different font fallback mechanism than IE and Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't display for me in the question, using chrome 23 and windows 7. Works in firefox though.

Comment: @devio . I don't have any of the listed fonts in my local machine. You want me to install those fonts.